# Passing Values from JavaScript to Django view.py

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

**Description: I have created a page. The page is running on http://127.0.0.1:8000/. There are three forms. I have one button separately. When I click on that button, all three form values need to be collected in Django view.py. But I'm having a problem with ajax request-response. The value arry1D is not getting at the Django view.py**

> Below is the separate button.

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input class="bg-yellow text-white" value="RUN" name="runModel" type="submit" 
   onclick="sendValuesToBack()">
</form>
```

> Below is the JavaScript Method.

```
            function sendValuesToBack()
            {
                let j,
                    i,
                    arry1D = [];

                for(j=0;j!=countName;j++)
                {
                    var inputs = document.getElementById("formId" + j).elements;
                    if (!arry1D[j]) arry1D[j] = []
                    arry1D[j][0] = "formId" + j;

                    console.log("---------------Form--------------------");
                    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                        if (inputs[i].nodeName === "INPUT" && inputs[i].type === "text") {
                            console.log("values of form:", inputs[i].value);
                            arry1D[j][i + 1] = inputs[i].value;
                        }
                    }
                }
                var tk = $(this).attr("data-token")
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/",
                    type:"POST",
                    data:
                        {   'arry1D':arry1D,
                            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': tk},
                    cache:false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(resp){
                        alert ("resp: "+resp.arry1D);
                    }
                });
            }
```

> view.py --> function from Django

```
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        arry1D = request.POST.get('arry1D')
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'arry1D': arry1D}), content_type="application/json")
```

> url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.index,name="index"),
    path('',views.getModelAttribute,name="index"),
]
```

**Error**

```
Internal Server Error: /form-post
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\views.py", line 39, in getModelAttribute
    return JsonResponse(json.dumps({'arry1D': arry1D}), content_type="application/json")
AttributeError: module 'django.core.serializers.json' has no attribute 'dumps'
[24/Jun/2020 15:34:30] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 16236
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? It appears you have two routes named "index" there, too, pointing to the same URL path.

Comment: So, I'm new to Django and ajax. The first URL is for getting the index page. In the second one, All three form values are coming from the same page that's why I wrote it. Should i write anything else?

Comment: Yes. do path('/form-post/', views.getModelAttribute, name="form_post") or something, then in your javascript put url: '{% url 'form_post' %}'; if that is the method you are posting the data to.

Comment: @MichaelHawkins yeah, you are right! I checked the jQuery Docs, this header is automatically added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple routes with the same name. Update the URLs to something like this instead (assuming the one named "form_post" is where you are sending the form data):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('/',views.index,name="index"),
    path('/form-post/',views.getModelAttribute,name="form_post"),
]
```

Then, in your javascript in the template:

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{% url 'form_post' %}",
                    type:"POST",
                    data:
                        {   'arry1D':arry1D,
                            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': tk},
                    cache:false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(resp){
                        alert ("resp: "+resp.arry1D);
                    }
                });
```

Lastly, use `JSONResponse()` instead of `HttpResponse()` when sending data back.

Comment: Hey! Michael. Thank you very much. I got the value of that variable on the django side. But I'm getting [24/Jun/2020 15:27:21] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 16217
Internal Server Error: /form-post error

Comment: What is the error from the console? Need the entire error. Also post the full updated view code if you can.

Comment: I have added the error in the question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Just pass the raw data to JSONResponse - return JSONResponse({'arry1D':arry1D}) and remove the "content type" portion. It is not needed.

Comment: Awesome sir. Finally, It worked. Thank you very much, Michael, you completely saved me.

Comment: Glad to help! Best of luck!